# Unable to remove text display if value = <null>

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, null, uilabel

I am trying to display some text in a label via the following code:

```
if (thisPhoto.userBio != NULL)
{
   thisUserBioLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisPhoto.userBio];
} 
else
{
   thisUserBioLabel.text = @"";                
}
```

However, I am having difficulty in removing the display if the value for `thisPhoto.userBio` is equal to `NULL`. I tried to print the value using `NSLog(@"%@", thisPhoto.userBio)` and I am getting the value `<null>`. How can I amend my code above such that I will not display the message if the value is `<null>`?

Comment: What is the label displaying when `thisPhoto.userBio` is equal to null?

Comment: It will display <null> in my label

Comment: @Joshua's solution should work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<null>` is what happens when the value is `NSNull` not `nil`. To do this you need to add an extra check to your first if.

`if (thisPhoto.userBio && ![thisPhoto.userBio isEqual:[NSNull null]])`

That will check for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

try with if `thisPhoto.userBio == NULL` ..

```
   thisUserBioLabel.text = nil;
```